# $H\otimes l^{2}(\Gamma)\cong\bigoplus\limits_{g\in \Gamma}H$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have no idea of proving $H\otimes l^{2}(\Gamma)\cong\bigoplus\limits_{g\in \Gamma}H$,where H is a hilbert space,$\Gamma$ is a discrete group, $l^{2}(\Gamma)$ is the set of all complex valued square summable fuctions on $\Gamma$.

Comment: So, my answer was incorrect. I deleted it subsequently

Comment: How to construct the bijection ?

Comment: You are rather looking for an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces. It is given by 
$$
 \phi : H \otimes \ell^2(\Gamma) \to \bigoplus_{g \in \Gamma} H; \quad  \phi(h \otimes f) = (f(g)  h)_{g \in \Gamma}. 
$$

Comment: How to  check the surjectivity?

Comment: Show that it is an isometry, and that the image of the algebraic tensor product is dense in  $\bigoplus\limits_{g\in \Gamma}H$